# Is there an easy way to access an array element via a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

With objects, I can wrap a key in square brackets like so:

```
// A.js

const category = 'foo'

return { [category] : 'bar' } // { foo: 'bar' }
```

Is there an easy way to do the same with array elements? Like

```
// B.js

const category = 'foo'
const items.foo = [1, 2, 3]
const item = 4

return { items: [...items.category, item] } // throws an error
```

I'd like to be able to get {items: [1, 2, 3, 4]} in B.js

Is there a way?

Comment: It should be `{ items: [...items[category], item] }`, and you should initialize items: - `const items = { foo: [1, 2, 3] }`.

Comment: I guess you want `{ items: [...items[category], item] }`

Comment: I want to access ...items.foo via ...items.'foo', just like I can access { foo: 'bar' } by { ['foo']: 'bar' } so that I don't have to hard-code foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the dot notation and square brackets are [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

If you use the dot notation, the property must be the actual property name:

```js
    words=new Object;
    words.greeting='hello';
    console.log(words.greeting);     //hello
    console.log(words['greeting']);  //hello
    console.log(words[greeting]);    //error
```

In the third example, `greeting` is treated as a variable, not as a string literal, and because `greeting` has not been defined as a variable, the JavaScript interpreter throws an error.

If we define `greeting` as a variable:

```
var greeting = 'greeting';
```

the third example works:

```js
    words=new Object;
    words.greeting='hello';
    var greeting='greeting';
    console.log(words[greeting]);
```

So you need to use square brackets as the property accessor:

```
[...items[category],item]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same syntax:

```js
const category = 'foo'
const items = {foo: [1, 2, 3]}
const item = 4
    
console.log({ items: [...items[category], item] })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the `foo` property using another variable, you can just use square brackets notation, like so:

```
const category = 'foo'
const items = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3]
}

const item = 4

console.log( { items: [...items[category], item] });
```